# Redmine installation: Mysql gem say undefined symbol: mysql_init

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems, installation, redmine

I'm trying to install redmine on a [OVH](http://www.ovh.com) mutualized server but i'm block by a MySQL gem issue.
OVH servers does not allow external network connection. I've downloaded and installed manually all gems with dependencies required for Redmine.

I've installed without any problems MySQL gems:
 - mysql 2.8.1
 - mysql2 0.3.11

For the installation I needed to specify mysql lib and include folders path because it's a mutualized installation and a non standard layout:

```
gem install mysql-2.8.1.gem
    --no-rdoc
    --no-ri
    --
    --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-lib=/usr/lib/mysql
    --with-mysql-include=/usr/include/mysql

gem install mysql2-0.3.11.gem
    --no-rdoc
    --no-ri
    --
    --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-opt-lib=/usr/lib/mysql
    --with-opt-include=/usr/include/mysql
```

With these 2 commands, I get no error and a message `1 gem insalled`.

After that funny manual package installation process, I've followed the [Redmine installation tutorial](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall) to initialize my environment.

First command, generate secret token: `rake generate_secret_token`
Second command, build database schema: `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate`

The first one work perfectly, but the second send me this error:

```
ruby: symbol lookup error: /MYHOMEFOLDER/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.so: undefined symbol: mysql_init
```

Is there someone who knows how I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `ruby1.9` then use the `mysql2` gem.
If you're using `ruby1.8` then use the `mysql` gem.

So, if you're using 1.9, in your `config/database.yml`

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
```

and :

```
gem install mysql2
```

If you're running Redmine >1.4, use `Bundler` instead of `gem install ...` !

Comment: I'm using `ruby 1.8.7` and the gem `mysql 2.8.1`.
In my database.yml, the adapter is `mysql`.

If i have the mysql2 gem installed, is it a problem even if i'm on ruby < 1.9?

Comment: I suggest you to remove these gems, then reinstall the right one. If the error persist, check if the dynlib is really present. Otherwise, you can check symbols present in a dynlib with the `nm` command.